# Spark Structured Streaming: Unexpected error: status: STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE = 0xC0000008

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming (v 2.3.0) job running on Yarn in client mode on a Hortonworks Cluster (v 2.6.5). The process read data from a Kafka topic, does a simple aggregation and then save results in another Kafka topic. Sometimes streaming process dies with following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Unexpected error: status: STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE = 0xC0000008 Path: checkpoint/offsets/.aed71241-c6f9-44ea-b47c-9ced9f6bc210.tmp with path="/checkpoint/offsets/.aed71241-c6f9-44ea-b47c-9ced9f6bc210.tmp", permission=644, clientname=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1385937308_1
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveCreate(DFSClient.java:1773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.createInternal(Hdfs.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.createInternal(Hdfs.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.create(AbstractFileSystem.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$3.next(FileContext.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$3.next(FileContext.java:684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.create(FileContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$FileContextManager.create(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.writeTempBatch(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$HDFSMetadataLog$$writeBatch(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$$anonfun$add$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$$anonfun$add$1.apply(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$$anonfun$add$1.apply(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:110)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.add(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Any ideas?

Regards, Alessio

Comment: What's the `checkpointLocation` option? Can you upgrade Spark to 2.4.4? It looks like a bug when Structured Streaming wants to write to WAL and failed. It should cause no issues though as you should simply resume the Spark app (the streaming query) from where it left off (died).

Comment: Here the checkpointLocation option: `.option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint")`. I can't upgrade Spark to 2.4.4 because in production I have this version on Hortonworks. Yes, if I resume the streaming query it starts when it left off with no issues but I would like to understand what causes this problem.

Comment: How do you start the Spark app? What's the `spark-submit`?

Comment: `spark-submit \
  --class <driver-class> \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --driver-memory 2g \
  --num-executors 2 \
  --executor-cores 3 \
  --executor-memory 3g \
  --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g \
  --conf spark.partition.multiplier=2 \
  --principal <principal> \
  --keytab <keytab path> \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=<application.conf-path> -Dlog4j.configuration=file:<log4j.properties-path>" \
  --queue <yarn-queue> \
  <jar-path> <arguments>`

Comment: I'm using Spark 2.4.4 on hortonworks platform, in my case job runs for 6-7 Hours and it dies with similar exception. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518735/spark-structured-streaming-unexpected-error-status-invalid-handle-with-path


Did you guys get any luck to resolve ???
If Yes, Please guide me the path.

Comment: @AlessioPasquini Try Updating the Spark Version.